# Why did lord Vishnu take Ram form

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama

Sita's shadow was taken by Ravan, since Ram knew that then why did he wage a war against Ravan. Did Lord Vidhnu take Ram avatar primarily to kill Ravan and it was all a plan?

Comment: Ram descended on earth 1. To show the ideal man 2. Because his bhakts wanted him to come down to earth 3. To slay the demons threatening the humans 4. Restore dharma.

Comment: There were many reasons for Ramavatara. They have been described in the Balakanda by Tulsidasji